# R: loop: How to create a column with mostly NA and value for some rows in a data.frame?

Tags: r, apply

I have some experience with apply family and plyr. Is there a better (non-loop) solution to this loop (takes a while since the data.frame has 200k rows).

```
for (i in 1:nrow(all)) 
 if (all$pmcCnt[i] > 0) 
  all[i,'linkPMC'] = sprintf('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=%s[uid]',str_replace_all(all$pmcpmids[i],'\\|','+'))
```

What it does is that: for rows that have >0 value in one column, a new column is populated with a URL. For 0 rows the URL is left blank.

My prior alternative code was generating too many empty links, hence the >0 condition.

```
all$link1=sprintf('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%s[uid]',str_replace_all(all$pmidsRaw,'\\|',','))
```

Again, the goal is to make it super fast. (takes 50+ seconds now) and/or more "R-ish" by not looping. (if possible/sensible)

Answer (score 2):

```
all$linkPMC <- ifelse(all$pmcCnt > 0, 
                      sprintf('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/?term=%s[uid]', str_replace_all(all$pmcpmids, '\\|','+')), 
                      NA)
```

Or replace `NA` with "" (empty string).